# Gitlab on Custom SSH Port

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have tried to install Gitlab, but i cannot enter a custom SSH Port.

Have already set the port in gitlab.yml to my custom Port, and created the file

```
/home/gitlab/gitlab/.ssh/config
```

With my properties:

```
Host localhost
Port 100001
```

as described [here](http://www.andmarios.com/en/2012/06/gitlab-on-an-ubuntu-10-04-server-with-apache/).

But it still shows the following message upon testing:

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
Starting diagnostic
config/database.yml............exists
config/gitlab.yml............exists
/home/git/repositories/............exists
/home/git/repositories/ is writable?............YES
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Can clone gitolite-admin?............YES
UMASK for .gitolite.rc is 0007? ............YES
/home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive exists? ............YES

Finished
```

and i cannot add my public ssh key in Gitlab, it says "GitLab was unable to access your Gitolite system."

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two problems.

The correct path for the configuration file is /home/gitlab/.ssh/config

You cannot use port 100001 as it doesn't exist. Ports range from 1 to 65535, I'd advise you though to use a port over 9000.

Comment: /home/gitlab/.ssh/config exists, and uses "localhost" for Host, and my correct ssh port for "Port". I just didnt want to post my port here. Thank you, but the problem remains..

Comment: Try to check if you really set up your ssh correctly.

Become the gitlab user (maybe [# sudo su -s /bin/bash gitlab]) and check if your ssh config works:
[# ssh git@localhost]. If you connect to gitolite, everything is fine with your .ssh/config and the problem is at gitlab.